# Hyperledger Updating asset and participant in a same transaction

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am testing the relationship in hyperledger.

My model file has a transaction `myTransaction` which has a relationship with Account using `from` variable.

Also this `from` (Account) has relationship with AccountHolder using `accountholder` in asset

```
/*
 * My first BlockChain Application
 */
namespace org.bahrain.rashidbank

asset Account identified by accountId {
    o String accountId
    o Double balance
    -- > AccountHolder accountholder
}

participant AccountHolder identified by accountholderId {
    o String accountholderId
    o String additionaldata

}

transaction myTransaction {
    -- > Account from
    o Double somenumber
    o String additionaldataa
    o String accountholderID
}
```

[image: Model file]

**My Javascript Script file is trying to update `balance` and `additionaldata` using the transaction object `rashidtransaction`**

```
/*
 * @param {org.bahrain.rashidbank.myTransaction} rashidtransaction
 * @transaction
 */
function anyfunctionname(rashidtransaction) {
    console.log("Passed Parameters", rashidtransaction);
    rashidtransaction.from.balance = rashidtransaction.somenumber;

    rashidtransaction.from.accountholder.accountholderId = rashidtransaction.accountholderID;
    rashidtransaction.from.accountholder.additionaldata = rashidtransaction.additionaldataa;


    return getAssetRegistry('org.bahrain.rashidbank.Account')
        .then(function(assetregistry) {

            return assetregistry.update(rashidtransaction.from);

        })
}
```

[image: Script File]

Following is the Transaction i am creating in the test page.
But throwing following error

```
t: Instance org.bahrain.rashidbank.Account#Rashid missing required field accountholder
```

[image]

Question: Why Can't I update the `AccountHolder.additionaldata` participant in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

First I don't think you'd be able to change the unique id while updating the asset. First, you have to delete that resource and create a new resource with that unique id.

To answer your question to in order to update account holder resource you have to update its own registry i.e You also have to update accounts registry as follows:

```
/**
 * @param {org.bahrain.rashidbank.myTransaction} rashidtransaction
 * @transaction
 */
async function anyfunctionname(rashidtransaction) {
  let assetReg = await getAssetRegistry('org.bahrain.rashidbank.Account')
  let participantReg = await getParticipantRegistry('org.bahrain.rashidbank.AccountHolder')

  rashidtransaction.from.balance = rashidtransaction.somenumber;
  rashidtransaction.from.accountholder.additionaldata = rashidtransaction.additionaldataa;

  await assetReg.update(rashidtransaction.from)
  await participantReg.update(rashidtransaction.from.accountholder)
}
```